# Jquery - Get the ID of an element using find()

Tags: jquery

how can i get the id of an element by using the find method?

**HTML**

```
<div id="d1" class="line1">blib blab blub </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

      // hit_id = $(".line1").find("blab").attr('id');
         hit_id = $(".line1").match(/blab/).attr('id');    

         $('body').append(' - '+hit_id+' - ');
});
```

**Working example**
http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/496/

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) for the text match, then [`.attr('id')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like you have for the ID, like this:

```
 var hit_id = $(".line1:contains('blab')").attr('id');
```

[You can see the updated/working version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Uaxwn/).

`.match()` isn't a jQuery function unless you're adding some plugin (see the console on your example page for the error: `Object...has no method 'match'`).  [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) will reduce the element set to those that have text containing what you pass as the string to [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) though, which seems to be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

```
var hit_id = $('.line1').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(/blab/);
}).attr('id');
```